# Need Help with Latex error!

Tags: errors

This keeps happening when I try to compile my document in TeXMaker.

```
Error : could not start the command : "pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "wow2".tex
```

Please Help!

Comment: usually that meas that you have just installed an editor  but not installed a tex system

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you installed a TeX distro (MikTeX/MacTeX/TeXLive)?

Comment: I have mactex installed

Comment: Im using a macBookk Air version 10.9.5 but Im not sure if this would have an effect on me not being able to compile.

Comment: Im also working on a Mac mini version 10.11.3 which compiles fine with the same downloads (TeXmaker/MacTeX)

Comment: Are the paths set correctly in the TeXMaker preferences?  For all the TeX programs they should be `/Library/TeX/texbin` (not `/usr/texbin`).

Answer (score 1):

MacTex 2017 is only available on 10.10 and higher. 
You have to update your MBA or use an older version from MacTex.

Comment: Instead of updating the OS the less invasive solution would probably be to directly install texlive without the mactex layer around it, just follow the instructions for unix install https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#installation Texlive 2017 works great with osx 10.9.5

Comment: @samcarter The newer versions of the MacOS run well on older machines, so upgrading the OS isn't necessarily a problem either.

Comment: @AlanMunn Its not really helpful that newer versions of MacOs run on the old machines when half of the functionalism you are used to is missing in the new OS :) I still have a huge list of features from 10.6 I am missing, only some of them I could replace with third party programs and other workarounds :( For normal programs updates bring new features, with MacOS I have the feeling more things are taken away then added.

Comment: @samcarter Fair enough.  It's a personal preference I guess. I can't even remember 10.6. But then again, I had a Mac Plus, so I have used every MacOS since the beginning. There have definitely been some new features. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn I can understand that people want to update their system for various reasons, but just for installing a tex distribution this seems like a big step if there are otherwise no reasons to update.